# Steppers suddenly disabled during job

Tags: marlin, stepper-driver, print-failure, bigtreetech

I'm using:

- Workbee CNC
- SKR1.4 Turbo with TMC5160
- Marlin 2.0

Steppers suddenly disabled during job. But, they get back working as soon as you restart the machine.

I've had the problem twice with this setup. Once with the Z-axis and once with the Y-axis (that uses two steppers, one keeps on working while the other was disabled).

When I had the problem in Z-axis, I decided to lower current on that axis from 2 A to 1.9 A. It's already 1.5 A for both steppers on the Y-axis.

Just switching off and on the machine is enough to let steppers work again say it seems not to be a wiring problem.

Any clue? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: What steppers do you use? NEMA 17 or 23? A current of 1.9-2 A means you need to actively cool the stepper drivers!

Comment: did you check the G-code? Does the board feel overly hot?

Comment: Hi,

I'm using Nema 23. The one configured with 2A are bigger ones. Steppers are warm but not hot. I can hold them in my hand indefenitly so I assume it's not too much current for them.

G-code is as generated by fusion 360. It includes long movements on the Y axis as I'm making a guitar neck. Its quite intensive on the CNC. Much wood to be removed.

Heat sinks tend to be quite hot. I can keep a finger on the top for around 3 s. This says noting on ship temperature that might well have exceded a limit.

My guess is overheating of drivers. I'll add a big fan and I hope this will fix it.

Comment: Check if your stepper drivers are overheating. Driving a nema23 motor is no joke, and at a 2A current, the drivers could be getting a little toasty, tripping the temperature limit and disabling the drivers.

Comment: Quick update : I've added a 120mm fan on top to the BTT card. Everything sems cold now.

First I thought it was OK but I had it twice again with Z axis. I had it 5 times now. Only comes on long jobs (after at least 1 hour of precessing). Any clue is welcome...

Bernard

Answer (score 3):

I think I fixed the problem.

Marlin was configured in hybrid mode with stealth chop mode at low speed then spread cycle when the stepper goes faster.

I removed stealth chop and set spread cycle at any speed and it seems to be OK.

I could let the machine work for hours with no issue

Comment: Nice to post your own answer, please don't forget to accept the answer! Thanks!